# Legendre transform and Minimax Theorems.

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, game-theory, duality-theorems

Denote the class of lower-semi-continuous convex functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}\cup\{\pm\infty\}$ by $Lscx(\mathbb{R}^n)$ ( so that only function attaining the value $-\infty$ is the constant $-\infty$ function). Denote by $\langle\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,\rangle$ the standard scalar product on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

> The classical Legendre transform $\mathcal{L}:Lscx(\mathbb{R}^n)\to Lscx(\mathbb{R}^n) $ is given by 
>   $$
> \mathcal{L}[f](u)=\sup_x(\langle x,u \rangle -f(u)).
> $$

And this transformation is well defined (see [here](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=GAA2XqOIIGoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Haim%20Brezis&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=Li5NVN_rC7LesATzu4HwDA&ved=0CB0Q6wEwAA#v=onepage&q=Haim%20Brezis&f=false) p.12) and
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathcal{L}\circ\mathcal{L}[f]&=&f,\\
f\leq g &\implies& \mathcal{L}[f]\leq \mathcal{L}[g]
\end{array}
$$
see [here](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=GAA2XqOIIGoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Haim%20Brezis&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=Li5NVN_rC7LesATzu4HwDA&ved=0CB0Q6wEwAA#v=onepage&q=Haim%20Brezis&f=false) **theorem 1**.

> **My Question:** Supose that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ we have $-F(x,\,\cdot\,)\in Lscx(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and for all $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ we have $F(\,\cdot\,,y)\in Lscx(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Under these assumptions the statement
>   $$
> \mathcal{L}[F(\,\cdot\,,z)](x)
> =
> \mathcal{L}[-F(w,\,\cdot\,)](y)
> \;\;\forall z,w\in\mathbb{R}^n
> \implies
> \max_v\min_u F(u,v)=\min_u\max_vF(u,v)\;
> $$
>   is true?

I'm trying to use **theorem 1** and **lemmas 1, 2 and 3** of this [Article](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v169-n2-p08.pdf).